# jQuery, Move Point and Get Coordination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please visit this link and run the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/crisply/mQYVY/

Explain briefly, Green box is added to gray area by clicking [Add box] button.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .draggable {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background: green;
            cursor: move;
        }
        #canvas {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            background: #ccc;
            position: relative;
            margin: 2em auto;
        }
        #results {
            text-align: center;
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            containment: "parent",
        });

        $('#btn_add').click(function () {
            var htmlData = '<div class="draggable"></div>';
            $('#canvas').append(htmlData);
            $(".draggable").draggable();
        });
    });
    //]]>  
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="canvas">
            <div class="draggable"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="results">coordination</div>
        <input type='button' id="btn_add" value='Add box' />
        <input type='button' id="btn_getCoord" value="Get Coordination" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition to this code, i want to implement more.

1. Click the **[Add box]** button, => **point generate random location**.
2. Click the **[Get Coordination]** button, 
   =>**get the coordination** of several points and express result div (yellow area).

Like this.

*-Coordination- 
 x:230, y: 222 
 x:122, y: 233 
 x:423, y:55 

x:50, y:30 
 ...*

Could you please give some components for me?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mQYVY/18/

```
$(function () {
    // This run when the document is ready, so it only effect on first point, it won't effect on new points automatically.
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
    });

    $('#btn_add').click(function () {
        var top = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 390);
        var left = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 490);
        var htmlData = '<div class="draggable" style="top:'+top+'px;left:'+left+'px;"></div>';
        $('.canvas').append(htmlData);
        // You need limit draggable containment for new point again.
        $(".draggable").draggable({containment: "parent"});
    });

    $('#btn_getCoord').click(function () {
        $('#results').html('-Coordination-');
        $('.draggable').each(function(){
            var cordInfo = '<br />x: '+$(this).position().left+', y: '+$(this).position().top;
            $('#results').append(cordInfo);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use: $(this).position().left instead of splice... :)

Comment: I have one more question. Why do not work **[containment: "parent"]** for new draggable div?.. New points can go out form the canvas. Thank you in advace

Comment: I have improved my code and added some comments to answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/mQYVY/10/

First part:

```
var htmlData = $('<div class="draggable"></div>');
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*501);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*401);
htmlData.css({'left': x+'px', 'top': y+'px'});
```

Second part:

```
$('#btn_getCoord').click(function() {
    var output = '-Coordination-';
    $('.draggable').each(function() {
        output += '<br />x: ' + $(this).position().left + ', y: ' + $(this).position().top;
    });
    $('#results').html(output);
});
```

Comment: I have one more question. Why do not work **[containment: "parent"]** for new draggable div?.. New points can go out form the canvas. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Updated JS for your first part:

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
    });

    $('#btn_add').click(function () {
        var top = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 390);
        var left = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 490);
        var htmlData = '<div class="draggable" style="top:'+top+'px;left:'+left+'px;"></div>';
        $('.canvas').append(htmlData);
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    });
});
```

For the second part follow this link: http://api.jquery.com/offset/